# How do I set a registry variable in batch code with SETX?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, windows-registry

I am trying to make a custom tool that works with Steam. Because the user may have a different install directory than myself, I want to use the `SteamPath` registry string value as a variable in my batch code to get the correct path. I am attempting to use the code below to make my custom `STEAMDIR` variable:

```
@ECHO OFF

SETX STEAMDIR /K "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam\SteamPath" /m

IF NOT EXIST "STEAMDIR" GOTO :NOSTEAM
IF EXIST "STEAMDIR" GOTO :FOUND

:FOUND
CLS
SET msgboxTitle=Success!
SET msgboxBody=Steam found!
SET tmpmsgbox=%TEMP%\Message.vbs
IF EXIST "%tmpmsgbox%" DEL /F /Q "%tmpmsgbox%"
ECHO msgbox "%msgboxBody%",0,"%msgboxTitle%">"%tmpmsgbox%"
WScript "%tmpmsgbox%"
GOTO :END

:NOSTEAM
CLS
SET msgboxTitle=Error!
SET msgboxBody=You don't kave any Kenshi workshop mods installed!
SET tmpmsgbox=%TEMP%\Message.vbs
IF EXIST "%tmpmsgbox%" DEL /F /Q "%tmpmsgbox%"
ECHO msgbox "%msgboxBody%",0,"%msgboxTitle%">"%tmpmsgbox%"
WScript "%tmpmsgbox%"
GOTO :END

:END
```

I am to use `SETX` as demonstrated IN [this](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) SS64 page, but my attempts have been unsuccessful. Any help is appreciated, but I'd like to ask that solutions using PowerShell or VisualBasic **not** be suggested. I get these a lot and I do not have enough experience in either language to re-write my code as I still have things to add.

Comment: But you're already running VBScript from within your batch script.

Comment: I am aware @grawity, it was made from a template using an answer I received on a different question. I will be adding `XCOPY` programming that is in batch and I do not know how to translate it.

Comment: You can still run the same xcopy.exe from within any other programming language, and I would honestly suggest that the overall framework better be written in something _not_ requiring such arcane hacks as `for /f` to do even trivial operations. Port it while it's still small.

Comment: I will have to decline your suggestion, I do not have the time right now to learn another language.

Comment: I'd suggest you to read a help for `set` command. You do the assignment completely wrong.

Comment: If you don't mind it requiring a second run you can set it with `setx` which can parse a value directly from the registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your previous formulation was better.
Besides the problem signaled by grawity, your main problem when using the
`for /f` command was that it produces separate variables for each token.

For your value of `c:/program files (x86)/steam`, you would have:

```
%%a=c:/program files
%%b=(x86)/steam
```

You would need to accumulate the values `%%a`, `%%b` etc. using code such as:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=3*" %%a in (`reg query "HKCU\Software\Valve\Steam" /V "SteamPath" ^| find "REG_SZ"`) do (
  set STEAMDIR=%%a
  set b=%%b
  set c=%%c
)  
if "%b%" neq "%%b" set STEAMDIR=%STEAMDIR% %b%
if "%c%" neq "%%c" set STEAMDIR=%STEAMDIR% %c%
echo STEAMDIR=%STEAMDIR%
```

For completeness, I have added a check for the third component, although there
isn't one for your value.

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed, thank you for putting this answer together!

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
SET %STEAMDIR%=for /f "tokens=3" %%a in [...] do echo %%a
```

The first problem is the usage of `%` on the left-hand side. In batch scripts, the percent signs aren't part of the variable's name; they're operators which trigger the *expansion* of that variable. You don't want them on the left-hand side of an assignment (except in special cases), because currently your command expands to this – which tries to set a variable with no name:

```
SET =for /f "tokens=3" %%a in [...] do echo %%a
```

The correct usage (of `SET`, not of the whole thing) would be:

```
SET STEAMDIR=for /f "tokens=3" %%a in [...] do echo %%a
```

The second problem is that the right-hand side of variable assignments *is the value*. It's not a command that produces this value. You're literally setting the variable's contents to the characters `for /f ...`

Other languages have functions or "command substitution" operators which allow running a command and using its output as the value of an outer command (e.g. `` var=`cmd` `` or `var=$(cmd)` in bash), but Windows Cmd.exe doesn't really have that.

Instead, the `for /f ...` invocation gets the output and runs inner command (the part after `do`), which can then access the output as the single-letter parameter `%%a`, `%%b`, etc. If the output needs to be stored in a "normal" variable, that needs to be done in the `for ... do` command, like this:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in [...] do SET STEAMDIR=%%a
```